Is it possible to solve Travelling Salesman Problem using Linkage Genetic Tree algorithm?
I'm researching LTGA algorithm and working with this implementation by the authours.
Algorithm is designed to solve DeceptiveTrapFunction or NearestNeighbourNK problems. I wonder if I could use a custom config for TSP problem and what should be changed in this case? Perhaps there are other implementations or ideas which I haven't found?
Thanks in advance.
